# youtube api - get timestamp of subscription

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am fetching all the Accounts that have subscribed to the authenticated user's channel.
Is there a way to obtain the timestamp of when the user has subscribed to the channel?

The default "publishedAt" sadly is of no help because that seems to be the timestamp of when the channel was created.
Also, that is not part of the "subscriberSnippet"-Section

Twitch and Mixer both provide "created_at", but the YouTube-API is a whole other story...

Thank you very much,
~ Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based from the official [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list#usage) of Youtube API:

> `Subscriptions: list`
>
> - retrieves a **list of channels** that the specified channel subscribes to.

You can view [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions#resource) the `subscriptions` resource and `publishedAt` is part of it:

> **snippet.publishedAt**   *datetime*
>
> The date and time that the subscription was created. The value is specified in ISO 8601
> (YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sZ) format.

You can try the ***[try this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions#snippet.publishedAt)*** section from the documentation and check your Youtube Subscibers List using Creator Studio by following the steps [here](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/7280745?hl=en).

> **Note:** The **list** only shows subscribers who have chosen to make their
> subscriptions public. When a user first joins YouTube, their
> subscriptions list is set to private by default.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here's an example in Python

```py
import requests

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer {0}'.format(token),
    'Client-Id': client_id
}
query = {
    'part': 'subscriberSnippet,snippet',
    'mySubscribers': 'true',
    'key': youtube_key
}
if cursor is not None:
    query['pageToken'] = cursor
response = requests.get(
    'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions',
    headers=headers, params=query)
res = response.json()
```

weirdly, `snippet` contains your authenticated user channel description and title but `publishedAt` field corresponds to when the item from `subscriberSnippet` subscribed to your authenticated user